Angular 16 Printer preview for Mobile app using capacitor
I have mobile application/s build with Angular 16 and Capacitor. I've been trying to show the print preview for the mobile application.
Standard approach with Windows.Print() is working only for the web and mobile web, but not for the native android application is not showing the print preview. I've triyed with this capacitor plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bcyesil/capacitor-plugin-printer which is opening the print preview as requered, but accept the html as string as per their documentation for example:
Printer.print({ content: '<h1>Lorem</h1>'})
I've tried to take the html as string from my component using Angular portal which works well for the html, but doesn't include the css from the scss file. Anyone have similar expirience? Or any help will be much appreciated.

In this case, you probably need a printWebView(...) method. With the help of media queries you should then be able to control the printed content (including your Angular component).
